# What is the subject of "My favorite place is Disneyland."?

Tags: subjects

> My favorite place is Disneyland.

What is the subject of this sentence?

Comment: A subject normally precedes the verb, so what do you think the subject here is?

Answer (score 1):

"My favourite place" is the subject in your sentence.

The subject of a sentence performs the verb's "action", and in this example, the verb is "is" (a form of *to be*).

> My favorite place *is* Disneyland.

Consider:

- Dogs like bones.
- Mark's dog likes bones.

In the first example, "dogs" are the subject; in the second it is more specific - "Mark's dog" is the subject. For the same reason, in your sentence, the subject is specifically "my favourite place", rather than just "place", which on its own does not mean anything because it is not specific enough.

Answer (score 0):

> **My  favourite place  is  Disneyland**

In  the sentence  *my  favourite  place*  is  subject and  Disneyland  is  the  subject  complement  used  predicatively.

We can  reverse  the  subject complement  as  subject  and  say without  much  difference in meaning.

> **Disneyland  is  my favourite  place**

Here  *Disneyland* is  the  subject and  *my favourite place*   is the  noun phrase  used  predicatively.

Both  the  sentences are in the active  voice and  they  can not  be  passivized  because  the  verb  **is**   is  an intransitive  verb.

Answer (score -1):

In your sentence, the subject is **place**.

This question is answered by the details that were provided. The subject and predicate differ in the below two sentences because a different noun is the subject in each instance.

**My favorite place is Disneyland** - passive voice: *place* is the subject

**Disneyland is my favorite place** -  active voice: *Disneyland* is the subject

The sentences say the same thing. The only difference is the first sentence conveys the message directly while the second version conveys it more indirectly.

Comment: Sorry, but you've got that wrong. The subject in "My favorite place is Disneyland" is the full NP "my favourite place". And both examples are active voice. Passive clauses are formed from active clauses with a transitive verb. But "be" is always intransitive, so it cannot be used to form passive clauses.

Comment: _Place_ is usually called "the simple subject".